# Redux - Reducer not being called

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

## Objective

I am trying to pass some objects I get back from Firestore into my reducer so I can display some results back to the user.

## Problem

When I try to call and pass the query to the reducer it does not appear to work. I am running a console.log to see if the reducer gets called but nothin it appearing. I think is because I have nested return statements?, Is this true?

Here is my action:

```
export const queryBidder = (value) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const normalizeValue = _.capitalize(value);
    let Query = []
    firestore.collection("bidders").where("firstname", ">=", normalizeValue).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching bidders.');
        return;
      }  
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        Query.push(doc.data());
        return { type: actionTypes.QUERYBIDDER, Query: Query };
      });
   
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
  }
};
```

When I put the return statement above the async return statement, all works well. However, I need to be able to call `getFirestore()`. This setup comes from a tutorial I found on Udemy, to be honest I don't quite understand it.

```
return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore })
```

How are these getting passed in? Where do they come from? Why does the order matter? How can I just access the `getfirestore()` function without wrapping my actions logic in this function?

Comment: I was able to resolve this by using dispatch instead of return.

Still would love to unerstand this setup a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of why this worked but while awaiting for responses I opted to change from return to dispatch.

`dispatch({ type: actionTypes.QUERYBIDDER, Query: Query });`

this resolved my issue. Look for a more thorough answer of why this worked and my above original questions.

Answer (score 0):

From redux documentation about using dispatch - `This is the only way to trigger a state change`. So basically if you want to change redux state you should dispatch an action with parameters - action type and new data.

You can read more about redux dispatch [here](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction)